# Email sent from web app has >> in bullet points

Tags: c#, html

I have a web application which notifies customers of their application status via email. Standard email messages are uploaded through a user web page. And is stored in a SQL server db table. The email web service then reads the message content from the db table, converts it to string and triggers the email.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader Msg = RC.dbTable("EmailMessage", parm);
                if (Msg == null)
                {
                    returnString = "Error Sending Email->" + RC.ErrorMessage("Error Getting Standard Email Message->");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Msg.Read())
                    {
                        msg = Msg["MessageContent"].ToString().Replace("[", "<").Replace("]", ">");
                        topic = Msg["MessageTopic"].ToString();
                    }
                    Msg.Close();
                }
```

This time, I had to include some bullet points in my email so I created the email message in word, saved it as HTML file and uploaded it to the web page. The email message shows up perfectly in any browser.

```
Hello,

Please reply to xyz@abc.com with the following:

‐      a paper

‐      a pen

‐      a file cover

This needs to be completed.

Stay Safe.
```

[image]
But, when I tested the email functionality, I am getting the email like this:

```
Hello,

Please reply to xyz@abc.com with the following:

‐      >>a paper

‐      >>a pen

‐      >>a file cover

This needs to be completed.

Stay Safe.
```

[image]
I don't understand why is the email message has >> in the bullet points text. Please find below the HTML file snippet.

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<link rel=File-List href="Hello_files/filelist.xml">
<link rel=themeData href="Hello_files/themedata.thmx">
<link rel=colorSchemeMapping href="Hello_files/colorschememapping.xml">
<style>
</style>
</head>

<body lang=EN-US link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72" style='tab-interval:.5in'>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif'>Hello, <br>
<br>
Please reply to </span><a
href="mailto:xyz@abc.com"><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:
"Verdana",sans-serif'>xyz@abc.com</span></a><span style='font-size:
12.0pt;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif'> with the following:<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst style='margin-bottom:8.0pt;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.25in;line-height:105%;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><![if !supportLists]><span
lang=EN-CA style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:105%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;
mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-bidi-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:
EN-CA'><span style='mso-list:Ignore'>&#8208;<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span></span><![endif]><span lang=EN-CA style='font-size:12.0pt;
line-height:105%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;mso-ansi-language:EN-CA'>a paper<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle style='margin-bottom:8.0pt;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.25in;line-height:105%;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><![if !supportLists]><span
lang=EN-CA style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:105%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;
mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-bidi-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:
EN-CA'><span style='mso-list:Ignore'>&#8208;<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span></span><![endif]><span lang=EN-CA style='font-size:12.0pt;
line-height:105%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;mso-ansi-language:EN-CA'>a pen<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle style='margin-bottom:8.0pt;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.25in;line-height:105%;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><![if !supportLists]><span
lang=EN-CA style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:105%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;
mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-bidi-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:
EN-CA'><span style='mso-list:Ignore'>&#8208;<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span></span><![endif]><span lang=EN-CA style='font-size:12.0pt;
line-height:105%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;mso-ansi-language:EN-CA'>a file cover<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;
margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:38.7pt;mso-add-space:auto;line-height:105%'><span
lang=EN-CA style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:105%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;
mso-ansi-language:EN-CA'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif'>This needs to be completed.<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;
font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif'>Stay Safe.<o:p></o:p></span></p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you give a screenshot instead? It feels like this is a character encoding issue, and the `>>` you reference is actually a `»`. Can you also show how the email text appears in the db, via some query tool?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have attached 2 screenshots (1 for the HTML file in word, 1 for the received email) and the HTML code snippet. One more thing, if I don't; create bullet points and just create hyphen with manual space then the email format comes perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh. MS Word was used to create the html. Hmm. Yes, it always makes a bit of a mess with all its crazy stylesheeting and masses of extra tags and other superfluous structure. You'd probably have a good result by just cleaning up the html to the minimum you need, which looks really simple - maybe 3 p and an ul, but I think the problem comes because of this:

```
msg = Msg["MessageContent"].ToString().Replace("[", "<").Replace("]", ">")
```

Plus these in the html:

```
lfo1'><![if !supportLists]><span
...
<![endif]>
```

Running that replacement will generate HTML that contains `<!<endif>>` which is definitely invalid html. Just because a browser can see it and not choke on it doesn't mean an email program will behave the same; you're putting garbage in and you're getting garbage out

Clean up the HTML:

```
<html>
<body style='font-face: sans-serif'>
<p>Hello,</p>

<p>Please reply to <a href="mailto:xyz@abc.com">xyz@abc.com</a> with the following:</p>
<ul>
<li>a paper</li>
<li>a pen</li>
<li>a file cover</li>
</ul>
<p>This needs to be completed.</p>
<p>Stay Safe.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And don't do that replacement of square brackets with angle ones. It's asking for trouble

Comment: Thanks, @Caius Jard.